# PathAnimator Safari stop/start issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, svg, safari, pathanimator

Can anyone confirm if there is a problem with this plugin in Safari? I've been trying to use it for a project and does exactly what I need it to but seems to stop/start eratically in Safari. What might be the problem?

http://dropthebit.com/demos/pathAnimator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past, just add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `.worker` class

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LENqbL)

```
    .walker{ 
       position:absolute; 
       z-index:1; font-size:25px; 
       color:deeppink; height:25px;
       width:25px; text-align:center; 
       line-height:25px; 
       margin:-93px 0 0 28px; 
       text-shadow:-6px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 7px 0; 
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp) for documentation